# Differential euqation for a pendulum: $ {d^2\alpha \over dt^2} + {g \over L} \cdot \alpha = 0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation $$ {d^2\alpha \over dt^2} + {g \over L} \cdot \alpha = 0 $$

describes a 1-dimensional mathematical pendulum, where $\alpha $ is the angle, $ g = 9.82 $, and $ L = 0.2 $ is the lentgh of the string. What is the position of the pendulum after 1 second if the velocity at time equals zero is $ 0 $ m/s and the angle at time equals zero is $ {\pi \over 60} $ radians.

To my understanding this is a homogenous equation, ergo

$$ y'' + Cy = 0$$

And with the help of the characteristic equation I get the complex roots $ Ci \, $ and $ -Ci $.

This is a farily simple differential equation, but I have a feeling my calculations so far are wrong (mainly because I didn't expect to see complex roots for this equation).

Comment: the solution is a sum of a cos and sin function

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057838/simple-second-order-differential-equation-of-the-form-fx-hx-0/1058947#1058947).

Comment: @Chinny845 wow, you're right.

Comment: @Chinny84, perhaps you should turn your comment above into an answer (even if it's just a link) so that this question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: @joelreyesnoche I would like to convert to cw here, but such a small body of text triggers the automatic creation of a comment..I will try in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above. As they say [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057838/simple-second-order-differential-equation-of-the-form-fx-hx-0/1058947#1058947) is one I done earlier :).

Glad it has helped.